# How to change paper-dropdown-menu default color

Tags: css, mixins, polymer-2.x

I am trying to set the default `paper-dropdown-menu` color from gray to black.

Using several mixins, I haven't been able to successfully change the color.

[image]

```
<paper-dropdown-menu
  label="Label" 
  on-iron-activate="_restructure"
  placeholder="[[placeholder]]">
  <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" 
    selected="[[item]]" 
    attr-for-selected="value">
      <paper-item">One</paper-item></paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

...

```
paper-dropdown-menu {
    --paper-input-container-focus-color: #3466F6;
    --paper-dropdown-menu-button: {
      color: black;
      opacity: 1;
    };
     --paper-dropdown-menu: {
      color: black;
      opacity: 1;
     };
      --paper-dropdown-menu-input: {
      color: black;
      opacity: 1;
    };
    --paper-input-container: {
      color: black;
      opacity: 1;
    };
     --paper-menu-button: {
      color: black;
      opacity: 1;
    };
  }
```

What CSS is needed to change the "Select Contact" color?

Comment: can you possibly create a jsfiddle with your code and I can play with it / get you a solution? It's just kind of difficult to know everything that could be affecting it without the html etc

https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good with jsfiddle...I think it's the placeholder text that I'm having issues with.

Comment: I can help you to set it up if you would like?

Comment: That would be awesome :)

Comment: You can take your code and separate it into the three boxes the HTML in the (top left), the CSS (top right), and if your using Javascript the (bottom left). Then if you click Run in the top left hand corner of the menu it will process your code and dsiplay how it is working in the result window (bottom right)

 is your code being hosted on a website somewhere or just locally? If it is hosted I can go look at the source code and put it in a jsfiddle for you and show you how it works

Comment: I get that part, but am not sure how to get the CDN setup to import `Polymer 2.x`, `paper-dropdown-menu`, etc.

Comment: so here is an example with your paper-dropdown-menu on codepen which is just like jsfiddle. -> https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/kXxAVa

They have used the

<base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.8.0/lib/">

tag to create a connection to an online hosted library and are creating the relative path in the following  

<link rel="import" href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">

 Then inside the script tag they refer to a js library they are using. If you copy the code between the head tags you should be able to access your CDN for the paper-dropdown